# Problem with global namespace on g++ 4.8.5 (maybe incomplete C++11 support)

Tags: c++, c++11, gsoap

I have prepared a project on an up-to-date computer using -std=c++11. Now, I have to compile it on g++ 4.8.5 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39). To my surprise, support for C++11 standard on this system seems to be incomplete. Please note, that the project depends on gsoap library which is also older on the production system.

I am using the following construct:

```
class GeoGrid : public ::GeoGrid::GeoGridServiceSoapBindingProxy
{
public:
  ...
  using ContextType = ::GeoGrid::GeoGrid2__ContextType;
  ...
}
```

I get the following error on the old system:

```
api-2-0.h:434:23: error: expected type-specifier before ‘::’ token
   using ContextType = ::GeoGrid::GeoGrid2__ContextType;
```

I do not know if this is produced due to the old gsoap or just old g++.

My question is if this can be resolved without upgrading the system? I have to admit that I do not completelly understand all the consequences of using ‘::’ token at the beginning, it was simply a lucky guess that works perfectly on the new system.

Comment: [:: at the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183185/before-a-variable-name-c)

Comment: Why do you think that the error message implies a lack of C++11 support? According to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html), GCC 4.8 supports practically all C++11 (core language) features.

Comment: so, do you think, that gobal namespace is perfectly and identically suported on both systems - then I have to look for the error elsewhere, probably different behaviour of gsoap

Comment: To rule C++11 support out as a concern, maybe you can try using a regular `typedef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet consistent with following situation:

```
/*
struct A {
    struct B {};
}; */

namespace X 
{
struct A {
    using B = ::A::B;    
};
}
```

producing with new gcc (v10)

```
error: 'A' in namespace '::' does not name a type
     using C = ::A::B;
```

or  this with old versions (v 4.7+)

```
 error: expected type-specifier before '::' token
     using C = ::A::B;
```

The error above is generated *only* in the case when there is no `A::B` (`GeoGrid::GeoGridServiceSoapBindingProxy` in your case) in global namespace, thus `::A::B` is not a legal typename, therefore compiler  considers `A` being a legal typename from current context's scope and messages about lack of required identifier of context before the scope divider `::`. The error message for newer versions is more readable than the technically correct but misleading older one.

Another version of this situation would be

```
struct A {
    using C = ::A::B;
    struct B {};
    
};
```

At the line where `using C` is present, `B` doesn't exist yet as a type, resulting in same error message for GCC 4.8. Newer versions would tell that type is incomplete.

```
 error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A'
     using C = ::A::B;
```

In both cases it's an indication of malformed program, not of lack of standard support.